# Extract an exact key from object in Underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

I am using the Underscore.js library. I want to extract an exact key from an object.

```
var student = {SID : 101; sname: "abc"}
```

I have tried like this.

```
var key = _.findkey(student, 'SID');
```

But it is showing 'undefined' in the key variable.
Help me.

Comment: Are you looking for `student['SID']` or `student.SID`? If not, what's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The [`_.findKey`](http://underscorejs.org/#findKey) can be used like this:

```
_.findKey(student, function(x){ return x === 101});  // returns 'SID'
```